# No beacon detected using altbeacon api

Tags: ibeacon

One iPhone is used to transmit ibeacon using locate app (the proximity uuid is 2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6). The android phone is used to detect the ibeacon. 
When I debug， I can get the following message:

> 08-30 15:33:57.051 D/BluetoothLeScanner(27939): onScanResult() - ScanResult{mDevice=6D:CC:9D:8D:3A:F3, mScanRecord=ScanRecord [mAdvertiseFlags=26, mServiceUuids=null, mManufacturerSpecificData={76=[2, 21, 47, 35, 68, 84, -49, 109, 74, 15, -83, -14, -12, -111, 27, -87, -1, -90, 0, 0, 0, 0, -59]}, mServiceData={}, mTxPowerLevel=-2147483648, mDeviceName=null], mRssi=-31, mTimestampNanos=58705755631306}

However in function `RangingBeaconsInRegion`, there is no beacon.

```
 void RangingBeaconsInRegion(object sender, RangeEventArgs e)
    {
             await ClearData();
             var allBeacons = new List<Beacon>();
             if (e.Beacons.Count > 0)
             {
                 foreach (var b in e.Beacons)
                 {
                        allBeacons.Add(b);
                        int rssi = b.Rssi;
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(rssi.ToString());
                  }

                        var orderedBeacons = allBeacons.OrderBy(b => b.Distance).ToList();
                        await UpdateData(orderedBeacons);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // unknown
                        await ClearData();
                    }
                }
```

The following is my implementation:

```
    public class MainActivity : XFormsApplicationDroid, IBeaconConsumer
        {
           public MainActivity()
            {

            }
            protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
            {

                BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.GetInstanceForApplication(this);
                var iBeaconParser = new BeaconParser();

                iBeaconParser.SetBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24");
                var parser = new BeaconParser();
                parser.SetBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25");
                beaconManager.BeaconParsers.Add(parser);

                beaconManager.Bind(this);
    }

    public void OnBeaconServiceConnect()
            {
                //obtain the beaconservie object of android 
                var beaconService = Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<IbeaconService>();
                beaconService.InitializeService();
                //beaconService.StartTransmitting();
                beaconService.StartMonitoring();
                beaconService.StartRanging();
            }

     public void InitializeService()
            {
                m_beaconManager = InitializeBeaconManager();
            }

    private BeaconManager InitializeBeaconManager()
            {
        BeaconManager bm =      BeaconManager.GetInstanceForApplication(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context);

                //set the scan window
                bm.SetForegroundScanPeriod(1100L);

                //subscribe to the events;
                m_monitorNotifier.EnterRegionComplete += EnteredRegion;
                m_monitorNotifier.ExitRegionComplete += ExitedRegion;
                m_monitorNotifier.DetermineStateForRegionComplete += DeterminedStateForRegionComplete;
                m_rangeNotifier.DidRangeBeaconsInRegionComplete += RangingBeaconsInRegion;


                // constructs a new region object to be used for ranging or monitoring
                m_tagRegion = new Region("myUniqueBeaconId", Identifier.Parse("E4C8A4FC-F68B-470D-959F-29382AF72CE7"), null, null);
                m_tagRegion = new Region("myUniqueBeaconId", Identifier.Parse("B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"), null, null);
                m_tagRegion = new Region("myUniqueBeaconId", Identifier.Parse("2F234454-CF6d-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6"), null, null);
                m_emptyRegion = new Region("myEmptyBeaconId", null, null, null);

                bm.SetBackgroundMode(false);
                // 
                //bm.Bind((IBeaconConsumer)Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context);

                return bm;
            }

public void StartRanging()
          {
             BeaconManagerInstance.SetForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(0L); 
            m_beaconManager.AddRangeNotifier(m_rangeNotifier);
            m_beaconManager.StartRangingBeaconsInRegion(m_tagRegion);
            m_beaconManager.StartRangingBeaconsInRegion(m_emptyRegion);

          }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at the code that sets up the beaconParsers, you'll see that two are constructed, but only one is added like this:

```
beaconManager.BeaconParsers.Add(parser);
```

Adding a second call to add the other beacon parser should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, that's my mistake! After I add a second call to add the other beacon parser! there is still some strange situation: I did not launch any beacon transmitter, but when I debug, I got the following message:

Comment: That does look like a Bluetooth LE advertisement being detected, but the bytes do not look to me like any known beacon format.  My guess is it is not coming from a beacon, but some other kind of device with Bluetooth LE.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that's my mistake! After I add a second call to add the other beacon parser! there is still some strange situation: I did not launch any beacon transmitter, but when I debug, I got the following output: D/BluetoothLeScanner( 6864): onScanResult() - ScanResult{mDevice=58:D6:74:3A:34:C5, mScanRecord=ScanRecord [mAdvertiseFlags=6, mServiceUuids=null, mManufacturerSpecificData={76=[12, 14, 0, 126, 81, 116, -16, 10, 52, 84, 15, 98, 113, 29, -15, 34]}, mServiceData={}, mTxPowerLevel=-2147483648, mDeviceName=null], mRssi=-89, mTimestampNanos=122142418198514}
08-31 09:11:13.943 D/BluetoothLeScanner( 6864): onScanResult() - ScanResult{mDevice=58:D6:74:3A:34:C5, mScanRecord=ScanRecord [mAdvertiseFlags=6, mServiceUuids=null, mManufacturerSpecificData={76=[12, 14, 0, 126, 81, 116, -16, 10, 52, 84, 15, 98, 113, 29, -15, 34]}, mServiceData={}, mTxPowerLevel=-2147483648, mDeviceName=null], mRssi=-89, mTimestampNanos=122142560625598}. It seems that one beacon is detected.